# Adding Combo Switch to Existing Switch Loop

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

This is lighting diagram for a room.
The existing wiring **(Lamp A)** is a switched loop.
The switch is a combo switch **(Blue Box)** and I want to use the unused second switch for the new lamp.
What I want to add is in the orange box. **(Lamp B)**

All the wiring is in the attic which I can access.

Since this is a switched loop, the terminals at the existing
switch are hot.

I have the black and white wires running to the unused switch.

Where do I connect back to neutral?

Are there any wiring diagrams for this arrangement?

How should I wire the new switch and wiring?

[image]

Comment: Is there somewhere else you can pull power from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

When you have a traditional **"switch loop"** like that, you can't extend anything off it.

The essential wires you'd need for anything else to come off it, *simply are not there*.

A lot of people get confused because they see black and white wires and think "those are the wires I need".  No.  **The wires are black and white because that's how cables are made**. In any given circuit, the black and white are reassigned to the needs of the moment depending on where it is.

On a switch loop, there is no neutral.  White has been re-tasked to be always-hot. Black is switched-hot.  No neutral, no circuit extension possible.